# Do I have to set SDKVersion in AndroidManifest.xml when defined in the gradle android closure?

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I use Android Studio and have the following in my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.majestella.test1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**Does this configuration automatically adds the following values to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file?**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

...
```

When I set permissions like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Does gradle overrides the permissions set in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 2):

gradle declaration automatically overrides what is in your manifest

Comment: When I set permissions does gradle overrides the permissions set in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: gradle does not do permissions

Answer (score 0):

Not always.
For example I was using some method which required an API above the current minimum. So I changed it in build.gradle and it did nothing to remove the warning. However once I added it in the Manifest it recognised it and removed the warning. I also double checked to make sure. So it's better practice to declare it in the Manifest itself if you are changing API levels from the original ones used when first creating your apps resource files. I do it whenever I make a complex app with a lot of classes unlike a test app.